# Writing a 100% test class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have written a trigger which takes the Country entered into the Account's BillingCountry Address Field (the trigger also does the same for the ShippingCountry too), and populates an ISO Country field.

The trigger uses a country mapping provided by a custom settings object called ISOCountry. The results can either be the ISO code, 'NULL' or '-'.

I am writing the test class, and can only get it to 80%. I would like to get this to 100% if possible.

I have tried to use the best practice as a guide to write this trigger, so it may have redundant methods/lines.

The Trigger -

```
trigger UpdateISOCodeAccount on Account (before insert, before update) {

Map<String, ISOCountry__c> isoCountryMap = ISOCountry__c.getAll();

for(Account a :trigger.new){

    if(isoCountryMap.containsKey(a.BillingCountry))
        a.testBilling_Country_Code_2__c= isoCountryMap.get(a.BillingCountry).Country_code__c;
    else a.testBilling_Country_Code_2__c= '-';
    if(a.BillingCountry == NULL) {a.testBilling_Country_Code_2__c = 'NULL';}

    if(isoCountryMap.containsKey(a.ShippingCountry))
        a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c= isoCountryMap.get(a.ShippingCountry).Country_code__c;
    else a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c= '-';
    if(a.ShippingCountry == NULL) {a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c = 'NULL';}
}
}
```

The test class

```
@isTest
public class testUpdateISOCodeAccount {

@isTest static void testUpdateAccountISOCode() {

    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>{};
    {
        Account a = new Account(Name='Test Account',BillingCountry='Australia',ShippingCountry='Australia');
    accounts.add(a);
}

    test.startTest();
    insert accounts;
    test.stopTest();

    List<Account> insertedAccounts = [SELECT Id,
                                          Name,
                                          BillingCountry,
                                          ShippingCountry,
                                          testBilling_Country_Code_2__c,
                                          testShipping_Country_Code_2__c
                                      FROM Account
                                      WHERE Id IN :accounts];

insert new list<ISOCountry__c> { 
        new ISOCountry__c(Name = 'Australia',Country_Code__c = 'AU'),
            new ISOCountry__c(Name = 'New Zealand',Country_Code__c = 'NZ')
            };

    for(Account a : insertedAccounts){
        System.assertEquals('Test Account', a.Name);
        System.assertEquals('Australia',a.BillingCountry);
        System.assertEquals('Australia',a.ShippingCountry);
        System.assertEquals('-',a.testBilling_Country_Code_2__c);
        System.assertEquals('-',a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c);
        //System.assertEquals('AU',a.testBilling_Country_Code_2__c);
        //System.assertEquals('AU',a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c);
        //System.assertEquals('NULL',a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c);
        //System.assertEquals('NULL',a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c);
    }
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Thanks

Test Class Updated...

```
@isTest
public class testUpdateISOCodeAccount {

@isTest static void testUpdateAccountISOCode() {

    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>{};
    {
        Account a = new Account(Name='Test Account',BillingCountry='Australia',ShippingCountry='Australia');
        accounts.add(a);
    }

    //test.startTest();
    //insert accounts;
    //test.stopTest();

    List<Account> insertedAccounts = [SELECT Id,
                                      Name,
                                      BillingCountry,
                                      ShippingCountry,
                                      Billing_Country_Code_2__c,
                                      Shipping_Country_Code_2__c
                                      FROM Account
                                      WHERE Id IN :accounts];

    insert new list<ISOCountry__c> { 
        new ISOCountry__c(Name = 'Australia',Country_Code__c = 'AU'),
        new ISOCountry__c(Name = 'New Zealand',Country_Code__c = 'NZ')
    };

                Account[] aList = new List<Account> {
                    new Account (name = 'Test Account 1', BillingCountry = 'Australia', ShippingCountry = 'AUSTRALIA'),
                    new Account (name = 'Test Account 2', BillingCountry = NULL, ShippingCountry = NULL),
                    new Account (name = 'Test Account 3', BillingCountry = 'AUSTRALIA', ShippingCountry = 'Australia')
                };

    Test.startTest();
    insert aList;
    Test.stopTest();

    Account[] aResList = [select ID, 
                          Billing_Country_Code_2__c, 
                          Shipping_Country_Code_2__c
                          from Account order by name];

    System.assertEquals('AU',aResList[0].Billing_Country_Code_2__c,'[0] billingCountry is valid');
    //System.assertEquals('-',aResList[0].Billing_Country_Code_2__c,'[0] billingCountry is valid');
    //System.assertEquals('NULL',aResList[0].Billing_Country_Code_2__c,'[0] billingCountry is valid');
    System.assertEquals('AU',aResList[0].Shipping_Country_Code_2__c,'[0] shippingCountry is valid');
    //System.assertEquals('-',aResList[0].Shipping_Country_Code_2__c,'[0] shippingCountry is valid');
    //System.assertEquals('NULL',aResList[0].Shipping_Country_Code_2__c,'[0] shippingCountry is valid');

    for(Account a : insertedAccounts){
        System.assertEquals('Test Account', a.Name);
        System.assertEquals('Australia',a.BillingCountry);
        System.assertEquals('Australia',a.ShippingCountry);
        System.assertEquals('-',a.Billing_Country_Code_2__c);
        System.assertEquals('-',a.Shipping_Country_Code_2__c);
        System.assertEquals('AU',a.Billing_Country_Code_2__c);
        System.assertEquals('AU',a.Shipping_Country_Code_2__c);
        System.assertEquals('NULL',a.Shipping_Country_Code_2__c);
        System.assertEquals('NULL',a.Shipping_Country_Code_2__c);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, you have to be careful with case sensitivity when checking a map's keys

Your line:

```
Map<String, ISOCountry__c> isoCountryMap = ISOCountry__c.getAll();
```

will return a map keyed by the custom settings key in whatever case the data was entered in, for example, `Australia`. So, if the user enters 'AUSTRALIA' in the form, it won't match and your logic will return a value of `-`. You'll need to decide how to deal with this by either ensuring the custom settings data is all lower or all uppercase and converting the lookup to that case in the trigger, or loading the custom settings into a map keyed in a consistent case. (Latter is best as you can't use validation rules on Custom Settings - you could use custom metadata types, these do allow for validation rules)

**Now, as for why you are getting 80% coverage?**

The answer is most likely that you are not mocking the custom settings. Custom settings do not just exist in testmethods, they have to be mocked

So, add the following into your test method.

```
insert new list<ISOCountry__c> { 
     new ISOCountry__c(Name = 'Australia',Country_Code__c = 'AU'),
     new ISOCountry__c(Name = 'New Zealand',Country_Code__c = 'NZ')
}

Account[] aList = new List<Account> {
     new Account (name = '00Name', BillingCountry = 'Australia', ShippingCountry = 'AUSTRALIA'),
     new Account (name = '01Name', BillingCountry = null, ShippingCountry = null),
     new Account (name = '02Name', BillingCountry = 'Foobar', ShippingCountry = 'Australia')};
Test.startTest();
insert aList;
Test.stopTest();

Account[] aResList = [select ID, testBilling_Country_Code_2__c, testShipping_Country_Code_2__c
                       from Account order by name];
System.assertEquals('AU',aResList[0].testBilling_Country_Code_2__c,'[0] billingcountry is valid');
... rest of asserts
```

As a further aside, triggers should be tested using lists of sobjects (Accounts) to make sure that you are performing the correct action to all members of the trigger list.

And, a final note to consider for the future - this type of logic belongs in a service layer class that can be called from various domain layer classes (trigger handlers) so you can reuse it for Accounts, Orders, Quotes, Leads and other objects that have countries.

Comment: Thanks cropredy. Unfortunately the added code didn't make a difference. I have added it to the initial posting. With regard to the literal string, the intention is that the Country is an exact match (meeting integration requirements) so there was some method to this madness!

Comment: @TheMikeyBosch -- Arpi Jakob has the additional clue; you need more test data. I've shown in the edited answer how you might go about that.

Comment: Hey cropredy. Thanks for the update. I now understand conceptually what i am missing, and have added the possible outcomes in the  System.assert. Some strange behavior though - Trigger says 100% but the test is failing at the System.assert (System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: [0] shippingCountry is valid: Expected: AU, Actual: -). I have added an updated test class above. I guess if you could, indicating what is redundant would be really useful too (unless the class is fit for purpose) I am struggling with format! Thanks!

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh - this is because the mocked Account uses `AUSTRALIA` as `shippingCountry` and the custom setting key is initial caps `Australia` - the `containsKey` method returns false and sets value to `-`

Comment: Hey cropredy. Updating this has resulted in the class being 100% and with no errors! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh : my pleasure.

Comment: Cropredy, ok, so wouldn't you know it, the requirement has now been modified to be case-insensitive! I have taken a look elsewhere to find out how to retrieve the value but with no success. Can you help?

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh - lol; please create a new question with title `How to do case insensitive match against list custom settings` and post the minimal amount of code to demonstrate what you have done so far (ignore the test method as that is not relevant). This way community will benefit from the question and answer

Comment: Yep, all good, you're right! cheers

Answer (score 2):

Since you are inserting a single Account. You will traverse this for loop exactly once. If you want every branch in this loop hit, you must insert additional Account records with fields that satisfy the entry condition into these branches, look for lines ending with '// No' bellow.

```
for(Account a :trigger.new){ // Yes

if(isoCountryMap.containsKey(a.BillingCountry)) // Yes
    a.testBilling_Country_Code_2__c= isoCountryMap.get(a.BillingCountry).Country_code__c; // Yes
else a.testBilling_Country_Code_2__c= '-'; // No
if(a.BillingCountry == NULL) {a.testBilling_Country_Code_2__c = 'NULL';} // No

if(isoCountryMap.containsKey(a.ShippingCountry)) // Yes
    a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c= isoCountryMap.get(a.ShippingCountry).Country_code__c; // Yes
else a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c= '-'; // No
if(a.ShippingCountry == NULL) {a.testShipping_Country_Code_2__c = 'NULL';} // No
```

}

For example: to hit this line

```
else a.testBilling_Country_Code_2__c= '-';
```

insert another  Account

```
new Account(Name='Test Account',ShippingCountry='Australia');
```

The Developer Console shows you exactly what line of code your test hits. So look for the red 'un hit' lines and construct the records you need to satisfy entry into those branches.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get to 100% coverage is to write multiple test methods, each testing a different event/outcome. You have only one method. Try writing a different method for each kind of value for the field.

Also, use System.runAs() so you can test user record access. Remember: YOU ARE 
TESTING FOR EVERY POSSIBLE OUTCOME, NOT PRIMARILY FOR CODE COVERAGE.

If you are going for 100% but aren't actually testing how users will use your code, then you are writing bad test code.